# allow multisite in the installation process

Tags: multisite, database, automation

So I want basically to automate wordpress installation for multisite, I looked a bit and found that I can do that using the *drop-in* plugin `wp-content/install.php`, It obviously works for normal wordpress installation but in multisite case, The database tables get created but the wp-site/wp-blogs tables are empty, so I can't access the site unless I insert the lines in the database manually.

Is there a function that does that ? or should I insert the lines in the database programmatically after installation ?

Comment: Have you looked into WP CLI? WP CLI can download install and setup WP from scratch in a script

Comment: Hello @TomJNowell thanks for commenting, is there another way other than CLI ? or is it the only way ?

Comment: Yes but to do it like this is unusual and rarely done. WP CLI simplifies the process immensely. Perhaps some context would be useful, why are you trying to do it this way? What you've done already is arguably harder than the basic CLI command you'd need to run with WP CLI

Comment: I can be wrong, but with CLI you have to write the commands everytime you want to install wordpress, also I can't control the default content(page/posts) generated after each subsite install, so what I'm trying to do is making some sort of a wordpress installation that enables and configures multisite on install, and since `wp-content/install.php` runs on every subsite installation, I thought it might be what I needed.

Comment: Controlling the default content in new sites is something you could ask about on this site, it's not an insurmountable problem, and it has little to do with how the site is created. Can you ellaborate more on the context? Your comment says what you're doing, which your Q already says, but it doesn't say why you're doing it, or the problem that it solves for you. The lack of context severely limits the types of answers and solutions you would get, as well as alternatives. This is an X Y problem, you've told us about your solution Y, and asked how to do it, but what's the problem X?

Comment: For example, are you trying to spin up new WP sites on a shared environment for new clients and want to automate the steps? Or is it something else? There are almost certainly better ways to do this that involve less effort, less steps, and work better

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell and thanks for your attention, my goal is to automate wordpress installation for multisite and the problem is that it is not an option you can check in the installation process so I can't just toggle it on, so I asked if there is a better way to do it other than what I've already tried.

Comment: I gathered that from your question, but you never said **why**, which prevents me from answering. E.g. is this in a local dev environment and you're trying to save steps? Is it because you're trying to implement a small hosting/referral program? Are you spinning up sites for new customers on signup? All those examples have potential solutions that aren't the one you outlined in your Q, but not all of them work with each example. I'm not going to take 40 minutes of unpaid time to type every possible permutation out for you in a giant answer that might not work

Comment: *facepalm* it's literally the first sentence in this other question you asked https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333574/override-the-wp-signup-php-file-multisite

Comment: With all due respect, I didn't force you to spend your precious time to help me.So I asked if I can do that in general, and if it's different from one case to another, I'm trying to have users register and create their own websites.